# How to raise a custom form invalid error in wizardview from django formtools

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-formwizard

I am using `django-formtools` to split the registration form. I have added `Google ReCaptcha` for captcha verification.
I would wish to produce error in the form like the one in `django UpdateView`.
Is there any method in `django form wizard` like

```
messages.error(self.request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
return super(UpdateUserProfileView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Here is my `done` method

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    """do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)."""
    recaptcha_response = self.request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
    values = {
        'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        'response': recaptcha_response
    }
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
    ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

    if result['success']:
        pass
    else:
        cleaned_data = super(UserProfileWizardView, self).get_all_cleaned_data()
        messages.error(self.request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        # raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.")
        # self.add_error('organization', 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        form = self.get_form(data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES)
        form.add_error('organization', 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        # context = self.get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
        # return self.render_to_response(context)
        return cleaned_data

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: To add error messages, only we need is request object. There are multiple methods which can access request. Please provide your `view` where you want to add these error messages.

Comment: @itzMEonTV I am trying to raise a form validation error like form_invalid. I have added my `done` method in the quesion

Comment: Try `MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
` in settings

Comment: Did you ever figured it to work?